# Need keyboard accessibility(tab+enter) on AntD sorter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In antDesign Table, sorter produces the default caret-up and caret-down icons.

As a requirement,

1. I need keyboard access using tabIndex="0" on the caret-up and on the caret-down icons for navigation.
2. And onKeyPress of Enter on caret-up/caret-down icons, I need them to getSorted.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Table } from 'antd';

const columns = [
 
  {
    title: 'Chinese Score',
    dataIndex: 'chinese',
    sorter: {
      compare: (a, b) => a.chinese - b.chinese,
      multiple: 3,
    },
  },
  {
    title: 'Math Score',
    dataIndex: 'math',
    sorter: {
      compare: (a, b) => a.math - b.math,
      multiple: 2,
    },
  },
  {
    title: 'English Score',
    dataIndex: 'english',
    sorter: {
      compare: (a, b) => a.english - b.english,
      multiple: 1,
    },
  },
];

const data = [
  {
    key: '1',
    name: 'John Brown',
    chinese: 98,
    math: 60,
    english: 70,
  },
  {
    key: '2',
    name: 'Jim Green',
    chinese: 98,
    math: 66,
    english: 89,
  },
  {
    key: '3',
    name: 'Joe Black',
    chinese: 98,
    math: 90,
    english: 70,
  },
  {
    key: '4',
    name: 'Jim Red',
    chinese: 88,
    math: 99,
    english: 89,
  },
];

function onChange(pagination, filters, sorter, extra) {
  console.log('params', pagination, filters, sorter, extra);
}

ReactDOM.render(<Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} onChange={onChange} />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

**Added picture of AntD**

[image: Added picture of AntD]